Build Error in .net project with multiple target frameworks: Could not find type 'System.Resources.NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute'
I am trying to convert an old .net framework project to have two target frameworks - 4.8.1 and 8.0 but I keep getting this build error:

Could not find type
'System.Resources.NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute' in assembly
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.8.1\Facades\System.Runtime.dll'.'

I have tried deleting the bin and obj directories, restarting visual studio etc but can't fix it. That attribute is in .net 4.8.1 so not sure why its not working.
This my .csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <UseWpf>true</UseWpf>
    <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    <AssemblyName>JacobsRevitTools</AssemblyName>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    <TargetFrameworks>net481;net8.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
    <StartAction>Program</StartAction>
    <StartProgram>c:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2025\Revit.exe</StartProgram>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);REVIT2019;REVIT2020;REVIT2021;REVIT2022;REVIT2023;REVIT2024;REVIT2025</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EPPlus" Version="7.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Extended.Wpf.Toolkit" Version="4.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="4.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="SmartFormat.NET" Version="3.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Resources.ResourceManager" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Caching" Version="8.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\JacobsToolsCommon\JacobsToolsCommon.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\JacobsToolsUI\JacobsToolsUI.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="AdWindows">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2025\AdWindows.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPI">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2025\RevitAPI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPIUI">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2025\RevitAPIUI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


I'd like to know how you converted your old .net framework project to have two target frameworks, did you do it via the Upgrade feature in this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-how-to-upgrade
or by modifying the .csproj file?

I modified the csproj file

If possible, could you provide the contents of your complete .csproj file? In addition, what older .NET Framework version are you using?

OK I added the csproj file above

OK so I eventually worked out that I needed to add conditions to the references in the csproj file like this:
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)|$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='net8.0-windows|Debug|x64'">
    <Reference Include="RevitAPI">
      <HintPath>c:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2025\RevitAPI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPIUI">
      <HintPath>c:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2025\RevitAPIUI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)|$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='net481|Debug|x64'">
    <Reference Include="RevitAPI">
      <HintPath>c:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2024\RevitAPI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPIUI">
      <HintPath>c:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2024\RevitAPIUI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>


Due to word limit, I cannot reply you in the form of comment. If the following method is useful to you, you can also mark it as answer:
There are two ways to set the NeutralResourcesLanguage type. I suggest you try one of the two methods to see if the problem still occurs:
1: Add code in AssemblyInfo.cs:
using System.Resources;
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")]

2: Add content in .csproj:
<PropertyGroup>
<NeutralLanguage>en</NeutralLanguage>
</PropertyGroup>

In addition, when I tried to upgrade the old framework project to the new two target frameworks - 4.8.1 and 8.0 projects, the same situation did not occur as you did. Your problem occurs in v4.8.1. I suggest you change this target framework to v4.8 or other .NET Framework versions to see if the problem still occurs.
